# matlab switch + regexp

Tags: regex, matlab

I tried to read up this but I think I might be fundamentally going about this the wrong way. Here's what I want:

- I have a unpredictable user-input value e.g. `a='test1'` that may vary a lot
- I want to test different scenarios for input strings, where some fuzzy matching should happen for all defined scenarios, but should revert to default if none apply

So ideally, I thought I want the case structure like this:

```
a='test1';
switch a
  case ~isempty(regexpi(a,'test','match','once')) %should handle all cases where 'test' is contained in the input string
    disp('this');
  otherwise %should handle everything else
    disp('that');
end
```

but it always outputs `that`.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Use `switch true`.

Comment: If you want a regexp it's more natural to use an `if`, rather than a `switch`

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar oh, wow, that's smart, I did not think of that, please post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, you are comparing the result of a boolean expression with the value you are testing, `a`.  This is never going to match so simply use `switch true` instead.

The cases are evaluated in order so this is equivalent to using an

```
if ...
    % Do something
elseif ...
    % Do something else
else
    % Otherwise
end
```

construction that some might argue is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a **`char`** (character array) `a` as the switch variable and a **`logical`** (true/false) expression result as a case, it will always go to otherwise because a **`char`** is not a **`logical`**.

You can use the logical expression result as the switch variable and use `true` as a case:

```
a='test1';
switch ~isempty(regexpi(a,'test','match','once'))
  case  true %should handle all cases where 'test' is contained in the input string
    disp('this');
  otherwise %should handle everything else
    disp('that');
end
```

Or simply use an if-else statement:

```
a='test1';
if ~isempty(regexpi(a,'test','match','once'))
    disp('this');
else %should handle everything else
    disp('that');
end
```